# bash input param value being set as 0 instead of value passed

Tags: bash

Using the following code, the DBUSER variable is always set as 0 instead of the value passed from the command line.

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong to cause DBUSER to be set to 0 instead of the actual value provided by the command-line input params.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
FIRST_DAY=$(date +%d)
LAST_DAY=$(date +%d)
MONTH=$(date +%m)
OUTPUT_FILENAME="usage_output.csv"
DBUSER=""
DBPASS=""

for ((i=1;i<=$#;i++)); 
do

    if [ ${!i} = "-sd" ] 
    then ((i++)) 
        let FIRST_DAY="${!i}";

    elif [ ${!i} = "-ed" ];
    then ((i++)) 
        let LAST_DAY="${!i}";

    elif [ ${!i} = "-m" ];
    then ((i++)) 
        let MONTH="${!i}";

    elif [ ${!i} = "-dbuser" ];
    then ((i++)) 
        let DBUSER="${!i}";

    elif [ ${!i} = "-dbpass" ];
    then ((i++)) 
        let DBPASS="${!i}";
    fi

done;

echo "${DBUSER}" "${DBPASS}"
```

Command-line:

```
./get_gs_neotek_usage.sh -dbpass 123456 -dbuser tester -sd 1 -ed 5 -m 9
```

the output is always

```
0 123456
```

regardless of what I pass as the value for -dbuser.  But all other input parameters are being set as expected.

Comment: What if you pass another parameter as first, so ie -dbuser tester -dbpass 123456 ...?

Comment: `let` is used to evaluate arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash converts any string value used in the assignment `let DBUSER="${!i}"` to `0`, simply use `DBUSER="${!i}"`.

`let` is used to perform [shell arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-arithmetic-evaluation).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using proper option parsing; `getopts` is limited in that it can't accept long arguments, but is standard POSIX so will always be available.

```
#!/bin/bash
FIRST_DAY=$(date +%d)
LAST_DAY=$(date +%d)
MONTH=$(date +%m)
OUTPUT_FILENAME="usage_output.csv"
DBUSER=""
DBPASS=""
while getopts ":s:e:m:u:p:" opt
do
    case $opt in
        s) 
            FIRST_DAY="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        e)
            LAST_DAY="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        m)
            MONTH="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        u)
            DBUSER="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        p)
            DBPASS="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "invalid option $OPTARG"
            exit
            ;;
        :)
            echo "$OPTARG requires an argument"
            exit
            ;;
    esac
done
echo "${DBUSER}" "${DBPASS}"
```